# How can I perform live migration of a docker container?

Tags: docker

Hi so this is a part of University project that we have to migrate a running docker container from one node to another node i.e if a docker container is running on node A I have to pause it then send it to some another node B and then resume it from the same state in which it was paused .
It would be helpful if someone can point me to some direction where I should look regarding this or some research paper.
Thanks

Comment: You can't migrate a Docker container any more (or less) than you can migrate any other process on Linux. Docker containers are just sets of process namespaces -- they don't change the fundamentals about how a program is executed in a way that makes it easier or harder to migrate than software that isn't containerized at all. (There *have* been various research projects around generic process state encapsulation, and in general, those projects' findings and results will apply with or without Docker involved).

Comment: ...*virtual machines* can be migrated with relative ease because related hardware is emulated, and so its state is encapsulated in software running in userspace, but that isn't true of Docker.

Comment: (BTW, I'm not sure that this question is topical here -- our scope is limited to specific, answerable problems encountered in the practice of writing software; administrative operations are outside of that purview).